# While adding data to Firebase an error occurs

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This error occurs while adding data to Firebase:

```
[{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
W/Firestore(27613): (24.9.1) [WriteStream]: (fecff26) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
W/Firestore(27613):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:223)
W/Firestore(27613):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:282)
W/Firestore(27613):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:318)
W/Firestore(27613):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/Firestore(27613):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/Firestore(27613):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
W/Firestore(27613): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
W/Firestore(27613):     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:156)
W/Firestore(27613):     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
W/Firestore(27613):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
W/Firestore(27613):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:631)
W/Firestore(27613):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:219)
W/Firestore(27613):     ... 5 more
W/Firestore(27613): Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
W/Firestore(27613):     at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
W/Firestore(27613):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:73)
W/Firestore(27613):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:202)
W/Firestore(27613):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:73)
W/Firestore(27613):     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:135)
W/Firestore(27613):     ... 9 more
W/Firestore(27613): }.
W/System  (27613): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2
I/System.out(27613): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(27613): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Unable to resolve host "firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
2
I/System.out(27613): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

I want a solution to successfully add data to Firebase.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection, if you are using an Emulator turn off and on the Network connectivity if not resolved the issue try on a Physical device.